# Create React App with Service Workers

Tags: react-redux, offline-caching, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I have upgraded my CRA to version 3.10.8 as it has built in support for PWA.
As a next step I have registered my service worker in the index.js and I think it got registered succesfully.
Now my main goal is to have some offline caching for our API calls (backend in Rails), so that when there is no network I can serve the cached response .
Is there anything else that I need to do to serve cached API responses.
When I built my app with Create react App, all it did was create a file called 
registerServiceWorker.js and then this gets called from the index.js.

Also the final app we are building is packaged with Codova so most of the Assets will be in local , our main aim is to cache the API calls. Is this the right way to go. We are using Redux for state management, but have not use any persistence as of now.
Any help/tips would be highly appreciated.

registerServiceWorker.js code below...

```
    // In production, we register a service worker to serve assets from local cache.

// This lets the app load faster on subsequent visits in production, and gives
// it offline capabilities. However, it also means that developers (and users)
// will only see deployed updates on the "N+1" visit to a page, since previously
// cached resources are updated in the background.


const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    // 127.0.0.1/8 is considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
);

export default function register() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (!isLocalhost) {
        // Is not local host. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl);
      } else {
        // This is running on localhost. Lets check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the old content will have been purged and
              // the fresh content will have been added to the cache.
              // It's the perfect time to display a "New content is
              // available; please refresh." message in your web app.
              console.log('New content is available; please refresh.');
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl)
    .then(response => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        response.headers.get('content-type').indexOf('javascript') === -1
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038668

Comment: Thanks for the info .Any other alternatives to other than Ejecting? From my understanding this would not work in IOS?

Comment: Another alternative would be https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/pull/2714, but that seems to be blocked. You could follow-up there if you'd like to see it implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Create-react-app version 3.

change the condition statement, Remove the codition (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' &&) it should only have if('serviceWorker' in navigator).

create your custom-service-worker file in public folder rewrite the following code as const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js` as swUrl = `./custom-service-worker.js`.

In the custom-service-worker.js file in public folder add the follow code, please refer the sample external api calls( place your api urls to be cached)

```
        importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-sw.js");

        if (workbox) {
                console.log('workbok loaded', workbox.routing)
        }

        //to cache the css html js and images files
        workbox.routing.registerRoute(
                /\.(?:js|html|css|images|svg)$/,
                new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst()

        );
        workbox.routing.registerRoute(
                'http://localhost:3000',
                new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst()
        );

        //to cache the external api calls
        workbox.routing.registerRoute(
                new RegExp('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'),
                new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate()
        );

        //to cache the external api calls
        workbox.routing.registerRoute(new RegExp('http://insight.dev.schoolwires.com/HelpAssets/C2Assets/C2Files/C2ImportUsersSample.csv'),
                new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate()
        );
```