# How to modify auto generated service-worker in Create-React-App

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app, sw-precache

I have created a sample app from Create-React-App library. When I ran the build command then it generates a service-worker on its own using `cache-first` strategy. 
But I need some more functionality like cache some API responses n all. I don't know how to modify the script which includes my own code in auto generated service-worker.
I have found some help lines for my case but these are not enough to get a whole understanding of it.

> By default, the generated service worker file will not intercept or cache any cross-origin traffic, like HTTP API requests, images, or embeds loaded from a different domain. If you would like to use a runtime caching strategy for those requests, you can eject and then configure the runtimeCaching option in the SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin section of webpack.config.prod.js.

Above paragraph is from official [doc](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

We had a similar problem while working on a project recently and we didn't want to "eject". We created a little tool that allows you to append custom service worker code to the one generated by CRA.

Have a look here: https://github.com/bbhlondon/cra-append-sw

Comment: Great workaround, thanks!
(if you run into `babel-loader` errors like I did during deployment, use the `--skip-compile` flag)

Answer (score 2):

You would can run [`npm run eject`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject) and get access to the underlying Webpack configuration.

Once you do that, the `webpack.config.prod.js` file can be modified to adjust your generated service worker. Look for the [section that configures `SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin`](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js#L319).

You can add in an additional [`runtimeCaching` configuration option](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache#runtimecaching-arrayobject) to that section to accommodate your runtime caching needs.

Comment: I don't like to eject because after ejection I have to handle every thing on my own. I am thinking to Fork the CRA itself.