# Where do I put the addEventListener for service worker in create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

The new `create-react-app` generates a [registerServiceWorker.js](https://pastebin.com/kMZCdgmf) file. I am following [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/debugging-service-workers/) tutorial and I want to add a fetch listener to the service worker. I am unsure where do I put my code.

I tried inserting a `registration.addEventListener` on line 15 (see the pastebin link). But the bundler removed it. I also tried adding a `navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener` in line 20 but that did not work as well.

Some sources[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038668/how-to-modify-auto-generated-service-worker-in-create-react-app) have mentioned that the app needs to be ejected. Is there a way to do it without ejecting?

Answer (score 0):

on the plugin page https://github.com/goldhand/sw-precache-webpack-plugin they say you can define any sw-precache options.

when you head to the sw-precache page https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-precache#options-parameter you will find an option runtimeCaching:

if you define runtimeCaching it should automatically add sw-toolbox to your project. You are now able to define for each urlPattern a handler like 'networkFirst' or 'fastest' (or write your custom request handler.) See example on the github page.

This is only theoretically how it should work, I never tried it myself, but I hope it gives you some assistance. (let me know if it works :-))