# React service worker add files to cache

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, sw-precache

Building the first React app based on create-react-app. It already have a service-worker.js in production build, but I need to add couple JavaScript (workers) files manually. These files are not included in the HTML and service worker do not cache them.

What is the correct way to add files to service worker cache list?

Comment: are you using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) ?

Comment: yes, I am using the create-react-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I did not find better solution, I decided to modify the file node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js

Find line

```
new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin({
```

and paste below

```
mergeStaticsConfig: true,
stripPrefix: './public/',
staticFileGlobs: ['./public/./js/jimp.min.js', './public/./js/jimp-worker.js'],
```

Comment: This is considered a bad practice, take a look at the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038668/how-to-modify-auto-generated-service-worker-in-create-react-app)