# Caching cross-origin API calls in create-react-app service worker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, service-worker

I am trying to convert a React web app to PWA (Progressive Web App). I have made the change in `index.js` file - `serviceWorker.register();`.

This is working fine as I am able to see the home page and assets in offline mode. But I want to cache API calls as well, which are cross origin.

I read `create-react-app` [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/) which say

> By default, the generated service worker file will not intercept or cache any cross-origin traffic, like HTTP API requests, images, or embeds loaded from a different domain.

I couldn't find ways to change this default behaviour and intercept/cache cross-origin API calls in the docs.

I stumbled on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038668/how-to-modify-auto-generated-service-worker-in-create-react-app) question from **2017** regarding the similar problem and solution seems to involve `eject`.

*Now that some time passed since the above question*, Is there any new way to intercept or cache any cross-origin traffic using `create-react-app` service worker without ejecting?

Comment: Does the solution propsed by @Wiyanto Tan solve the problem?

Comment: @Fi3, it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I never done this before, but you can try to comment this condition in serviceWorker.js file:

[image]

Comment: Will try this out and confirm.